# Android: Click on a link without id or class using javascript inside a webview

Tags: javascript, android, class, click

I need to perform a click on a specific link. Unfortunatly I can't control the html page and what I have is this:

```
<table width="10%" height="44px" cellspacing="0px" border="0" padding="0px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="https://www.example.com/test">
<img border="0" src="https://www.example.com/images/img.png">
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="https://www.example.com/test2">
<img border="0" src="https://www.example.com/images/img2.png">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tried something like this:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings faller = view.getSettings();
    String url = "http://donnow.net/test/test.html";
   faller.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   view.loadUrl(url);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('table').getElementsByTagName('td')[1].getElementsByTagName('a').click();");
             }
          });

}
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you can't call `getElementsByTagName()` repeatedly on itself - that function returns an `HTMLCollection` of elements and the `getElementsByTagName()` function can't be applied again to that.

One approach to use instead could be:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[x].childNodes[y].click()
```